# Django - Unit test object's delection does not work as expacted

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-views, django-unittest

For 2 of my models, Users and Groups, I have a view to delete objects. The code is almost the same for each of them, it works in the application but unit test have different results: it works for users, not for groups.
Thanks in advance for your advises.

Here are the unit tests:

```py
class TestAdmUsers(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.company = create_dummy_company("Société de test")
        self.user_staff = create_dummy_user(self.company, "staff", admin=True)
        self.usr11 = create_dummy_user(self.company, "user11")
        self.usr12 = create_dummy_user(self.company, "user12", admin=True)
        self.usr13 = create_dummy_user(self.company, "user13")

        self.client.force_login(self.user_staff.user)

    def test_adm_delete_user(self):
        test_usercomp_id = self.usr13.id
        usrcomp = UserComp.objects.get(user__username="user13")
        self.assertEqual(usrcomp.id, test_usercomp_id)

        url = reverse("polls:adm_delete_user", args=[self.company.comp_slug, test_usercomp_id])
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        with self.assertRaises(User.DoesNotExist):
            User.objects.get(id=test_usercomp_id)
        with self.assertRaises(UserComp.DoesNotExist):
            UserComp.objects.get(id=test_usercomp_id)

class TestAdmGroups(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.company = create_dummy_company("Société de test")

        self.user_staff = create_dummy_user(self.company, "staff", admin=True)
        self.usr11 = create_dummy_user(self.company, "user11")
        self.usr12 = create_dummy_user(self.company, "user12", admin=True)
        self.usr13 = create_dummy_user(self.company, "user13")
        self.usr14 = create_dummy_user(self.company, "user14")

        user_list = [self.usr11.id, self.usr12.id, self.usr13.id, self.usr14.id]
        users = UserComp.objects.filter(id__in=user_list)
        self.group1 = UserGroup.create_group({
            "company": self.company,
            "group_name": "Groupe 1",
            "weight": 40,
            },
            user_list=users)

    def test_adm_delete_group(self):
        test_group_id = self.group1.id
        grp = UserGroup.objects.get(group_name="Groupe 1")
        self.assertEqual(grp.id, test_group_id)

        url = reverse("polls:adm_delete_group", args=[self.company.comp_slug, test_group_id])
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        with self.assertRaises(UserGroup.DoesNotExist):
            UserGroup.objects.get(id=test_group_id)
```

The test runs fine for users, but I have this fali for groups:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Mes
> documents\Informatique\Developpement\Votes
> AG\projet_votes\polls\tests_admin.py", line 354, in
> test_adm_delete_group
> UserGroup.objects.get(id=test_group_id) AssertionError: DoesNotExist not raised

Here are related models:

```py
class UserComp(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Utilisateur")
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Société")
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^0[0-9]([ .-]?[0-9]{2}){4}$', message=("Format de numéro de téléphone invalide"))
    phone_num = models.CharField("numéro de téléphone", validators=[phone_regex], max_length=14, null=True, blank=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField("administrateur", default=False)

class UserGroup(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="société"
    )
    users = models.ManyToManyField(UserComp, verbose_name="utilisateurs", blank=True)
    group_name = models.CharField("nom", max_length=100)
    weight = models.IntegerField("poids", default=0)
    hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And the views:

```py
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser or (u.id is not None and u.usercomp.is_admin))
def adm_delete_user(request, comp_slug, usr_id):
    del_usr = User.objects.get(pk=usr_id)
    msg = "Utilisateur {0} {1} supprimé.".\
            format(del_usr.last_name, del_usr.first_name)

    User.objects.get(pk=usr_id).delete()

    messages.success(request, msg)
    return redirect("polls:adm_users", comp_slug=comp_slug)

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser or (u.id is not None and u.usercomp.is_admin))
def adm_delete_group(request, comp_slug, grp_id):
    del_grp = UserGroup.objects.get(pk=grp_id)
    msg = "Groupe {0} supprimé.".format(del_grp.group_name)

    UserGroup.objects.get(pk=grp_id).delete()

    messages.success(request, msg)
    return redirect("polls:adm_groups", comp_slug=comp_slug)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no logged in staff on your `TestAdmGroups` test class so it most likely does not run the delete, but fails on `user_passes_test` (which returns a 302).

So to fix, just log in the staff user in `TestAdmGroups`:

```py
class TestAdmGroups(TestCase):
    ...
    self.client.force_login(self.user_staff.user)
```

Comment: Damned you're right! I missed this point because there are other unit tests linked to the `setUp()`. I will not be able to test before end of this day but I will confirm as soon as it will be possible. Thanks!

Comment: I confirm it works, thanks again!